# Detect not regular rectangular object does not work correct

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I would like to detect not regular rectangular objects using OpenCV and approxPolyDP function. In the image I have 4 windows that can be approximate as rectangular contour using the approxPolyDP. But Im not able to detect all of them when set up certain threshold. I filter the windows using the wodth and the height and the angel between the vertices. I would like to have more robust code that can detect all 4 windows. Any help?Here my code

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 using namespace cv;
 using namespace std;

 Mat src; Mat src_gray;
 int thresh = 5;
 int max_thresh = 60000;
 RNG rng(12345);

 void thresh_callback(int, void* );

 static double angle(Point pt1, Point pt2, Point pt0)
 {
     double dx1 = pt1.x - pt0.x;
     double dy1 = pt1.y - pt0.y;
     double dx2 = pt2.x - pt0.x;
     double dy2 = pt2.y - pt0.y;
     return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);
 }

 void setLabel(cv::Mat& im, const std::string label, std::vector<cv::Point>& contour)
 {
    int fontface = cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
    double scale = 0.4;
    int thickness = 1;
    int baseline = 0;

    cv::Size text = cv::getTextSize(label, fontface, scale, thickness, &baseline);
    cv::Rect r = cv::boundingRect(contour);

    cv::Point pt(r.x + ((r.width - text.width) / 2), r.y + ((r.height + text.height) / 2));
    cv::rectangle(im, pt + cv::Point(0, baseline), pt + cv::Point(text.width, -text.height), CV_RGB(255,255,255), CV_FILLED);
    cv::putText(im, label, pt, fontface, scale, CV_RGB(0,0,0), thickness, 8);
 }


int main()
{

    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("p3.png");
    resize(src, src, Size(640,480), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);

     char* source_window = "Source";
     namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
     imshow( source_window, src );

     createTrackbar( " Canny thresh:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );
     thresh_callback( 0, 0 );

waitKey(0);
return(0);
}

void thresh_callback(int, void* ) {

    src = imread("p3.png");
    resize(src, src, Size(640,480), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
    //================================
    Mat gray,bw,dil,erd;

    Canny(gray,bw,thresh, thresh*1, 5);
    //Canny( src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*1, 3 );
    dilate(bw,dil,Mat());
    erode(dil,erd,Mat());
    Mat tmp=bw.clone();

    Size kernalSize (15,20);
    Mat element = getStructuringElement (MORPH_RECT, kernalSize, Point(4,4)  );
    morphologyEx( bw, bw, MORPH_CLOSE, element );
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;//novo
    findContours(bw.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    vector<Point> approx;
    Mat dst = src.clone();

    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true) * 0.09, true);

        if (approx.size() >= 4.0 && (approx.size() <= 4.1))
        {
            int vtc = approx.size();
            vector<double> cos;
            for(int j = 2; j < vtc + 1; j++)

            cos.push_back(angle(approx[j%vtc], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
            sort(cos.begin(), cos.end());
            double mincos = cos.front();
            double maxcos = cos.back();

            if (vtc == 4 && mincos >= -0.6 && maxcos <= 0.6)
            {
                Rect r = boundingRect(contours[i]);
                double ratio = abs(1 - (double)r.width / r.height);
                if (r.height >50 && r.width >20 && r.height < 640 && r.width < 640 && r.height>r.width ) /* constraints on region size */
                                {
                //Rect r = boundingRect(contours[i]);
                //double ratio = abs(1 - (double)r.width / r.height);
                line(dst, approx.at(0), approx.at(1), cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
                line(dst, approx.at(1), approx.at(2), cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
                line(dst, approx.at(2), approx.at(3), cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
                line(dst, approx.at(3), approx.at(0), cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
            }
          }
        }
    }

    }
```

Here the source image

[image: source image]

And here detected windows
[image: detected rectangles]

Here the drawing/visual contours
[image: contours]

Comment: please draw/visualize the extracted contours. You'll probably see, that your problem is the extracted area from canny+morphology

Comment: in red are the detected contours by certain threshold. How to draw/visualize the extracted contours?

Comment: drawContours

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=drawcontours#drawcontours

Comment: ok. done it. Please see the edits

Comment: sa you can see, only the window on the right is one well defined contour as you want to have it, while the left one includes the while parts around the window. That's why the approx-poly is rotated etc. (tries to include the white part, too)

Comment: so any suggestions how  to make it robust and detect all 4 windows?

Comment: no, it's a hard task in general. Maybe try segmentation of dark areas instead of using canny, if you want to fix your approach. But don't expect wonders ;)

Comment: How about if try to detect shape  with 6 points and check if error is less than a threshold or may be use Hue moment?

Comment: or any other approach that can work?

Comment: sorry, way too broad for SO. Computer vision isnt simple most of the time...

Comment: so should I maybe ask in some computer vision forum? Any special forum such complicated task?

Comment: probably they exist... on StackExchange there is a digital signal processing site. Unfortunately the Computer vision site wasnt created yet...